# Using an django-sass-processor library in django but refuses to apply the style because its MIME type is not a supported stylesheet

Tags: django, sass, django-compressor

I'm using Sass for my Django(3.2.6) website with the help of libraries called [django-compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor) to compile it to a **.css** file. It works fine during development but when I try to disable the DEBUG mode in the settings the error will pop-up.

> Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/styles.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Setting up the library I've added the following code to my **settings.py** (between ---- lines):

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    'sass_processor',
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'openfiles.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates'))],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'openfiles.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Here are my static directory files structure BEFORE running library:

```
    .
├── public (folder for images)
├── _scss (folder for .scss files)
└── styles.scss
```

AFTER running library, it created two files called **styles.css.map** and **styles.css**:

```
.
├── public 
├── _scss 
├── styles.css
├── styles.css.map
└── styles.scss
```

To access scss tags, HTML now use **{% load scss_tags %}** tag, here is my **head.html**:

```
{% load sass_tags %}
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" rel="profile">
  <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="{% url 'index' %}/humans.txt">

  <!-- Enable responsiveness on mobile devices-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">

  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ site_title }}">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ site_brand_name }}">
  <meta property="og:url" content="{% url 'index'} %">
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ site_description }}">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:image" content="{% sass_src 'public/meta-img.png' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v2.0.1/css/unicons.css">

  <title>
      {% block title %}
            Open Siena Files
      {% endblock title %}
  </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% sass_src 'styles.scss' %}" >

  <!-- Icons -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% sass_src 'public/favicon.ico' %}">
</head>
```

But when running it without DEBUG mode the browser produces the error. YES YES YES. I already search for a solution but nothing seems to fit with specific problem I have about library converting scss to css.